# -[CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, calayer, nsautoreleasepool, nszombie

I'm developing an iphone app and when I turn on my NSZombieEnabled I have regularly a crash on error :

```
*** -[CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xe6012e0
```

It always come when I push or pop a view in my view controller. Sometimes there's this error before :

```
-[UIApplication endIgnoringInteractionEvents] called without matching -beginIgnoringInteractionEvents. Ignoring.
```

What does it mean? Anyone has a clue or has encountered this problem?

Thank you very much for help!

Romain

Comment: Ok I have partially found out why it crash. For those who encounter the same issue, check out this link : http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/12864-message-sent-deallocated-instance.html

The problem was that I released some ViewControllers in my dealloc method.
Never do that, this is made automatically whenever push/popViewController are called.

I think there's still some bugs left since I encountered once this error in my 10 last tests.

Comment: For those who got the same kind of error check this other question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238823/i-dont-know-why-my-view-is-freezing

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This likely means you are trying to retain an object a UI object, such as a UIButton, that was released.  There are a number of ways to track down this issue but if you can narrow down where this is occurring in your app, I generally start commenting out releases until I see where the problematic release is.  My guess is you released something that was autoreleased.

Answer (score 2):

If the above answers did not help then check if your code is using KVO in the class where you receive this error. When KVO is sending a message to your observing class about a value on a key changing, if the class has been released by ARC then KVO will be trying to alert a non-existent address in memory about that changes, causing your app to throw this error.

Consider this, a class called `MyViewController` and you want to observe when the `bounds` property of it's `view.layer` changes indicating a layout change from landscape to portrait. So you add the line:

```
// self is MyViewController
self.view.layer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bounds", options: .new, context: nil)
```

This will alert your class if the `view` size changed.

But if your viewController is dismissed, say a `UINavigationController` pops it off the stack, KVO is still going to try and alert `MyViewController` the view's bounds has changed (because now it's gone). Then when KVO does this your application is going to crash. In your debug console you would see the following message:

```
-[MyViewController retain]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

This is because you must remove the observer (`MyViewController`) for that keyPath. It is best to do this before `MyViewController` is dismissed, ike so:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.view.layer.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bounds")
}
```

Now when you attempt to pop `MyViewController` from the navigation stack there will be no error.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to something more than `@Tony` 's answer. As it is correct.

You might be using `UI object's layer` or its `sublayer`. So just check actually UI didnot got released before using it;

```
if(UI object) //has instance
{
   //now use UI object.
}
```